# Print output to Tkinter text widget

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a script which uses beautifulsoup to scrape a site for product barcodes, and have pieced together bits of code to try and make a basic GUI with Tkinter.  First there's an entry box to ask for the URL, then I want to output that set to a Tkinter text widget.  It's the last part I can't do.  When I try to put text into another example i get a name error on text.insert.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
import urllib2
import bs4 as bs
import re
import urlparse
import sys
master = Tk()

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def callback():
    url = e.get()

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    content = response.read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
    barcodes = set()
    for tag in soup.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile(r'/pi/')}):
        href = tag['src']
        scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urlparse.urlsplit(href)
        barcodes.add(path.split('\\')[1])
##    print "\n".join(str(x) for x in sorted(barcodes)) This would output to the shell.


b = Button(master, text="go", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
```

I want to launch the other text window and print the barcodes to it if it has values.

```
##if len(barcodes) != 0:
##
##        import Tkinter
##        import ScrolledText
##        root = Tkinter.Tk(className=" Just another Text Editor")
##        textPad = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)
##        textPad.pack()
##
##        root.mainloop()

mainloop()
```

I have been looking through the Tkinter docs for about a day now, but no progress.  Would appreciate any pointers.  Atthe moment is says barcodes is not defined, so i am obviously doing something else wrong.

Comment: what is the exact error that you are getting on using `text.insert`?

Comment: So i did a more basic example lifted from another site, which just opens a text widget and I put in text.insert(Tkinter.END, "hello").  Which returns NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: to add to the above, that script has import Tkinter at the top

Comment: & did you write `text=Text` before that? If not kindly visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm)

Comment: Thanks very much, that helped.  Another question: so when i try to implement that in the second half of the code it says name barcodes is not defined.  but that was defined as a set earlier in the script, why does it need to be defined again?  Sorry if this is stupid.

Comment: no question is stupid...you can either make a `class` & use `self` so that you can use it anywhere in the `class`. or you can declare it `global`.what might be happening is you declared it in one method & called it in another & since its `local`, it cannot be used outside the method